# Xcode 9.0 bug can't drag drop to exit icon

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9

I faced a problem after updating to XCode9.0 i wasn't able to connect an outlet of a navigation Item Button to the "exit icon" on the storyboard scene to perform later on an unwind segue. 
i'm not sure if the bug was in the UINavigationItem or in the exit icon
but the way it worked for me eventually was by copy-paste the scene then deleting the origin and after clean build folder (that's where you go on the product menu and hold the option key) it worked just fine.

Comment: I'm seeing this too.. what are we missing?

Comment: i had a reply from Apple after reporting this bug , their answer was 
"make sure that you prepared the unwind segue method before trying to connect the UIButton to the exit icon on the sotryboard".

what i noticed is that if you still can't connect UIButtons on the exit buttons 
just rename the segue method , clean .build and it works fine 
i really couldn't find any further explanation , but let's not forget that xcode 9 is still a beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also make sure you have included the @IBAction keyword in the unwind method.

Answer (score 0):

if this problem happens with you :

first : make sure that you created the unwind prepare for segue method in your code before ctrl-dragging the UIButton to the "exit icon" on the storyboard Scene.

second :if you're still having a problem with ctrl-dragging just rename the unwind prepare for segue method and it should work